# Symfony 4, Object and SubObjects, missing foreign keys

Tags: forms, symfony

I am not able to find the trick to get the following.

Say I have two `Entity`: `Main` and `Minor`, `Main` one-to-many `Minor`, `mainId` being the foreign key field.

I wish to have both a (Minor) form  to create a `Minor` object, such that users may select its `Main` object from a list of already available `Main` objects, and a  (Main) form to create a `Main` object and possibly many different `Minor` (sub)objects at once.

The issue is that in the latter case, I am not able to save the foreign key.

For the Minor form, I define:

```
$builder ->add('minorTitle')
         ->add('Main', EntityType::class, array(
               'class' => Main::class,
               'choice_label' => 'mainTtile',
               'label' => 'main'))
```

have `'data_class' => Minor::class`, and it works fine.

For the Main form, I tried:

```
$builder
        ->add('mainTitle')
        ->add('Minors', CollectionType::class, array(
              'entry_type' => MinorType::class,
              'allow_add' => true,
              'label' => 'Minor'
              ))   

              'data_class' => Main::class`
```

So the Minor form is indeed embedded as a subform within the Main one. To add more subforms, I have some JS  as suggested in [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). To avoid to display the `Main` field in the Minor subforms, I have hacked a little the `prototype`, by something like:

```
newWidget = newWidget.replace(newWidget.match(/\B<div class="form-group"><label class="required" for="main_Minors___name_Main">Main<\/label><select id="main_Minors___name_Main" name="main\[Minors\]\[__name__\]\[Main\]" class="form-control">.*<\/select>\B/g),"");
```

A user is able to create  a Main object, and many Minor ones too, but the `id` of the former is not saved as the foreign keys of the latter ones. I have tried to fix things within the Main Controller by something like (or variants):

```
public function new(Request $request): Response {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $main = new Main();
    $form = $this->createForm(MainType::class, $main);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $postData = $request->request->get('main');

        $minors = array();
        foreach($postData['Minors'] as $key => $obj){
            $minors[$key]= new Minor();
            $minors[$key]->setMain($main);
            $minors[$key]->setMinorTitle($obj['minorTitle']);
            $em->persist($minors[$key]);
        }

        $em->persist($main);
        $em->flush();
   }
```

but either it does not work, or it saves twice the same subobject (only once with the correct foreign key).

(Maybe, I could fix by two different MinorType classes, but I would like to avoid that)

Thanks

Comment: can you please show more of your form types and your controller (where you create the forms) and setter/getter/adder/remover of the entity classes? where does `$spartito` come from? you only give glimpses of data. is your MainType not with `'data_class' => Main::class`? Why don't you use `$form->getData()`? so much confusion and questions ...

Comment: My stuff is more complicated, so I am trying to explain myself with a concocted example. I am trying do edit (and I have corrected a couple of misprint).

Comment: glad it works now, and apparently your controller code got simpler too (which is good). well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a number of hints.

1. your form types should have the [`data_class`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data-class) **option** set to the appropriate class.
2. your form field names should match the property name on the entity. (and by default, all property names are in camelCase, lowercase first char ... in symfony)
3. after 1. and 2. you get proper entities by just calling `$form->getData()` (or, as you might have noticed, when you give the `createForm` call an entity, it will be modified by the form component - this might not always be intended. consider Data Transfer Objects (DTO) for when it's not intended.)
4. your `CollectionType` field should have **option** [`byReference`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference) set to `false`, such that the setters get used on the collection field (`Main::setMinors`, in this case).
5. usually the one-to-many side (i.e. `Main` class) can get away with:

   ```
   public function setMinors(array $minors) {
       foreach($minors as $minor) {
           $minor->setMain($this); // set the main, just to be safe
       }
       $this->minors = $minors;    // set the property Main.minors
   }
   ```

   but you should **not** do this in `setMain` in reverse too (it's also not so trivial. alternative to `setMinors` are `addMinor` and `removeMinor`, there are benefits and costs for either solution, but when it comes to forms, they are quite equivalent, I would say)
6. on `Main` if you set the `cascade={"PERSIST"}` option on the `OneToMany` (i.e. `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Minor", cascade={"PERSIST"})`), you don't have to explicitly call persist on all minors, they will get persisted as soon as you persist (and flush) the `Main` object/instance.
7. Finally, either add an option to your minor type, to omit the `main` form field, or add a new form type `MainMinorType` (or whatever) that doesn't have the `main` form field (extend `MinorType` and remove the `main` field). This removes the necessity for dirty hacks ;o)

However, overall, if you don't set the minors on the main in a bi-directional relationship, the results are not clearly defined. (just assume for a moment, A has a link to B, but B doesn't have a link to A, but should have, because it's a bi-directional relationship. It could mean, that the link has to be established. It could also mean, that the link should be removed. So, to be safe and clearly communicate what is intended, set both sides!) And ultimately, this might be the reason it doesn't work as intended.

**update**

To elaborate on point 7. Your `MinorType` could be amended like this:

```
class MinorType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        // ... other fields before
        if(empty($options['remove_main_field'])) {
            // field is the same, but isn't added always, due to 'if'
            $builder->add('main', EntityType::class, [
               'class' => Main::class,
               'choice_label' => 'mainTtile',
               'label' => 'main'
            ]);
        }
        // ... rest of form
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        // maybe parent call ...
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // your other defaults
            'remove_main_field' => false, // add new option, self-explanatory
        ]);
    }
}
```

in your `MainType` you had, the following, to which I added the new option

```
       ->add('Minor', EntityType::class, array(
               'class' => Minor::class,
               'remove_main_field' => true, // <-- this is new
       ))
```

now, this will remove the main field from your minors forms, when it's *embedded* in your main form. the default is however, to not remove the main field, so when you edit a minor by itself, the main field will be rendered, as it was before ... unless I made a mistake in my code ;o)

Comment: See edit, and thanks. I am not sure about your 7., _add an option_. Let me know please.

Comment: @mario I added an update. it was slightly too much for a comment ;oD

Comment: cute, i'll try and report.

Comment: @ Jakumi: it works, though you swapped things around, see my update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mario I'm not sure what you mean, as far as I can tell, it's exactly the changes that I added. care to point out, what is different?

Comment: in the MainForm you add `->add('Minors', CollectionType::class`; you wrote `->add('Main', EntityType::class`, didn't you?

Comment: @mario you were right, I inserted the same form twice ^^

Comment: i got the clue form you. thks. If you have time, I have a more general question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208163/symfony-4-manytomany-association-with-attribute-custom-form-to-insert-attribut)