# Symfony 4. ManyToMany association with attribute. Custom form to insert attribute value, how do I?

Tags: symfony

A Symfony 4 project. I am not able to see ho to code the following spec.

Say I have two entities Alpha and Beta. 
When I create an Alpha object alpha, I wish to associate (ManyToMany) to it one or more Beta objects. I know how to render new and edit Forms to do so.

I wish to enrich the AlphaBeta join table with an attribute, say the *Cost* to associate a Beta to an Alpha. The issue is that I am not able to enrich the forms above as to insert or edit a *Cost* value, when I create a Alpha object and associate to it a Beta object.

Is there a standard way to code a situation of this kind?

I read that the way to go is to have two OneToMany associations Alpha->AlphaBeta, and Beta->AlphaBeta, but even doing so I am not able to define/render a Form for Alpha as to create a new Alpha object, to associate to it a Beta object (or more) and to assign to such association a Cost value.

Your advise is very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I did find a way, indeed it is pretty straightforward Synfony 4 code.
Hope it could be useful to somebody.

(note: I used `php bin/console make:entity/crud/form` to write the needed scripts. Below how I needed to modify the code I got from `make`)

So, say I have Alpha and Beta entities. 
I wish to have a form to create a new Alpha object, to associate to it one or more Beta objects, and to fill in a Cost value for each Alpha-Beta association. I want a edit form too.

First I create a new AlphaBeta entity, whose fields are:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Alpha", inversedBy="alphabetas", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $alpha;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Beta", inversedBy="betaalphas", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $beta;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $cost;
```

Within class `Alpha`, I need

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AlphaBeta", mappedBy="alpha", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $alphabetas;
```

with usual '`getAlphaBeta`, `addAlphaBeta` and `removeAlphaBeta` methods. (similarly for `Beta`)

I create usual CRUD controllers for the new `AlphaBeta` entity. To have an AlphaBeta Form which could be used as a subform too, I define

```
class `AlphaBetaEmbeddedForm`  extends AbstractType {

      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder ->add('Beta', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => Beta::class,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'choice_label' => 'betaTitle' ))
             ->add('cost', TextType::class);
   if(empty($options['remove_alpha_field'])) {
   $builder->add('Alpha', EntityType::class, array(
                   'class' => Alpha::class,
                   'multiple' => false,
                   'expanded' => true,
                   'choice_label' => 'alphaTitle'
    ));}}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => AlphaBeta::class,
        'remove_alpha_field' => false,
    ]);
}}
```

`remove_alpha_field` is the [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959102/solved-symfony-4-object-and-subobjects-missing-foreign-keys) that let me use the form above as a subform within a form to create an `Alpha` object:

```
class AlphaType extends AbstractType {

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

     $builder
        ->add('alphaTitle')       
        ->add('AlphaBetas', CollectionType::class, array(
           'entry_type'  => AlphaBetaEmbeddedForm ::class,
           'entry_options' => ['label' => true, 'remove_alpha_field' => true],
           'allow_add' => true,
           'label' => 'Betas',
           'by_reference' => false
    ));}
```

To render the subforms within the main form, I need some JS, as suggested [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html), to be inserted within the `new.html.twig` and `edit.html.twig` templates for `Alpha`:

```
{% block javascripts %} <script type="text/javascript"> 
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add-another-collection-widget").click(function(e){ 
          var list = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('data-list-selector'));
          var counter = list.data('widget-counter') | list.children().length;
          var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
          newWidget  = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter); 
          counter++;
          list.data('widget-counter', counter);
          var newElem = jQuery(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
          newElem.appendTo(list);
    });});</script>{% endblock %}
```

To apply the latter, it seems you need to write each single row in the main form template `_form.html.twig`:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="my-custom-class-for-errors">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
     <div id="alphaTitle">
        {{ form_row(form.alphaTitle) }}
    </div>

{% if  form.AlphaBetas %} 
     <b>Betas</b> </br></br>
 {% for Beta in form.AlphaBetas %}
   {% for BetaField in Beta %}
     {{ form_row(BetaField) }}
   {% endfor %} 
       {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}

<div id="AlphaBeta-fields-list"
    data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.AlphaBetas.vars.prototype)|e }}"
    data-widget-tags="{{ '<p></p>' |e }}"
    data-widget-counter="{{ form.children|length }}">
{% for AlphaBetaField in form.AlphaBetas.vars.prototype.children %}
{{ form_row(AlphaBetaField) }}
{% endfor %}
</div> 

<button type="button" id="add-another-collection-widget" data-list-selector="#AlphaBeta-fields-list">Insert Beta</button>
</br>
<button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

That's all.

Note: within the main form to edit an Alpha object, I would like to insert a delete buttons for each Beta associated object. As much as I can see, it is not possible, since it would mean to insert a html form within an html form. Since I may delete a AlphaBeta association by the corresponding AlphaBeta delete action, it is not a big deal.

If you see how I can improve my code, you are welcome to advise me.

Comment: to remove an alphabeta you technically could just remove the corresponding html (js). you also can add "remove" buttons (same form) and check in code, if the submit button was pressed or not. if a remove button was pressed, adapt the collection accordingly. however, you can either remove or update in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the relation/association itself should have an attribute, then the many-to-many mapping in doctrine isn't sufficient anymore, since associations can't store additional data. So you correctly note, that you need an extra `AlphaBeta` entity/class that holds the data. (As already posted by Ali Kazemi, [there is a tutorial for this](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/many-to-many-extra-fields))

But you wonder about how the cost field can be added to your form...

Since the `cost` is part of the `AlphaBeta` entity/class in your case, the form field should be in a form type `AlphaBetaType` that - probably depending on the options provided - should render an `AlphaType` and/or `BetaType` sub form, and a `cost` form field. Custom form themeing can display it in a way, that it doesn't appear as if it was a subform, if that is a concern. (However, it should be noted that custom form theming can be annoying at times...)

In general, the form structure/hierarchy usually very much resembles the entity structure/hierarchy. And only sporadically hiding data or mapping/transforming it to be displayed or handled differently.

*Alternatively* you can [add an unmapped form field](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/unmapped-fields) and later store that in your `AlphaBeta`, but that on average isn't simpler, since it involves "manual" handling.